# Problem with login with facebook button

Tags: authentication, facebook

```
    </html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://rgksugan.in/"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"><iframe>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'194541653919499', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
<fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
</body>
<html>
```

This is my HTML page. I am expecting a Login with Facebook button in my page. But it doesnot appear. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi are you embdding facebook connect code in your html tag? Other thing you have to load your jsdk either synchronously or asynchronously. Put the code of like button after that. First make your html tag like this
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en">`
 
and then try this just after your <body> tag

```
<body>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({ 
            appId:'194541653919499', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
};
   (function() {
     var e = document.createElement("script");
     e.type = "text/javascript";
     e.src = document.location.protocol +
     "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
   }());

 </script>
```

Use this code for your like button. Your third problem is that you are having two facebook connect statements in your code. When you have connected with facebook using a asynchronously then you dont need to connect again when you are putting like button code. use this code

```
<fb:like href="http://rgksugan.in/" show_faces="true" width="450" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

iframe end tag of your like button is not well formatted.

**Change** 
`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://rgksugan.in/"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"><iframe>`

**to**

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://rgksugan.in/"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```